# Windows with space to write text dont appear AJS

Tags: javascript, plugins, jira

I have created custom Issue Tab Panel with field, where I can add comment when Ill press my custom button “add comment”

In my VM template I have

```
AJS.$("#add-comment-button").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        AJS.dialog2("#add-status-comment").show();
    });
```

This button works fine and window to write text appears, but… In other section in Issues --> Current Search —> Views (Detail Views), windows with space to write text dont appear when I click button “add comment”. It only appers in normal view of issue… Whats problem?

Comment: Those views are separate and don't share the same VM template, the same case is with issue details view on agile board, even though those views looks similar or the same, in the code, they are different pieces.

Comment: @enterbios still not works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question right so I'll give it a try. Maybe it helps in one or the other way.

As you didn't provide the code affecting the window I assume it is possible you are retrieving the issue key or issue id. There are some Jira JS calls that don't work in every view. The reason is unknown to me, but maybe if you use different calls it will work.

Here is the question and answer to this field availability problem on the atlassian community: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Get-issueID-in-JavaScript-in-Project-Screen-viewing-issue/qaq-p/824175

Otherwise you should provide some more information.

Regards
Chris